# Jquery dialog() Should i load dialog content using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, dialog

I have a page with several jquery Ui buttons that calls dialog() to open specific forms. I currently have all the forms on the same page marked as hidden. So when a specific button is clicked, the dialog will open showing the specific form. My questions is, is it better to have all the formss on the same page marked as hidden, or is it better to have all the forms in a separate file and then use .ajax to call a specific forms from the file using it's ID. Any other thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the complexity of the page and the forms. If your page loads quickly having the forms already loaded will insure that they "pop" very quickly for the user. However if the extra code in the forms is causing your page load times to degrade it might be better to load them using AJAX. There isn't a real right or wrong global answer. However if you don't have AJAX on your resume yet. . . there is an advantage to using the latter.